# White-spaces in java

Tags: java, whitespace

In c we can do the following:

```
int p  = printf(" ");//valid statement
```

So we can either increase the value of p and spaces will increase. Is there a way we can do this in java. Just curious.

Comment: Don't you think that trying it out is faster than posting this off-topic question at SO?

Comment: what does mean by increase the value ??as i understand printf return the number of arguments in c

Comment: `printf` in C returns the number of characters printed (in this case 1). Java's `print` or `println` and so on (under `System.out`) are void methods, so no. You can however simply set `p` to your output string size such as `int p = str.length(); System.out.println(str)`

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: You dont need to think that i didn't try it. Coz if didn't try it, i wouldn't ask a question like this. So, i did tried it, unfortunatley i just started java and i m not so good, which is apparent from my question. And please care to explain how can this be off-topic, coz to you it might be stupid question to you. But if you think open mindedly, there is no such thing as a stupid question, only stupid answers. Anyways the guy below did gave me a way to do it...

And by the way, int p = System.out.print(" "); didnt work for me. So yeah i tried. AND I M A ROOKIE.

Comment: @OriLentz: So in that way  i can increase the str length later at  my will in case if i need to increase the white spaces in a statement. Thanks, that was kool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your Question is looking Ambiguous. please elaborate.
As far i understand v You can do following.
String p= new String(" ");
   p+=p;   //increase

Comment: Exactly what i wanted, although in C its different and easy. I wanted to increase the white-spaces at my will.  And you gave me the exact logic

Comment: What i wanted to perform was this: int p = System.out.print(" "). But this is not  right since System.out are void methods.I just wanted to increase the space between two characters in a loop. so i needed this alternative. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

So you could do the same in Java like:

```
String myString = "     ";
int p = myString.length();//will assign 5 i.e. length of myString.
```

Comment: Thanks, that was some alternative i was dying to get.

Answer (score 0):

No, print() function in java has void as a return type. You have to improvise as suggested by @SMA

Comment: Yeah, i got it. I havent reached that deep in java but i will remember it now